# Server migration troubles with Imagick, Fopen, PHP and Permissions

Tags: php, linux, permissions, fopen, imagick

I've recently migrated linux servers.

I'm currently getting this error when trying to upload an image using Imagick from a form.

```
Warning: fopen(/home/user/public/website.com/public/images/users/current/thumb/username.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/user/public/website.com/public/inc/functions/functions.php on line 864
```

The code that is run resides in a function:

```
try{
    $im = new Imagick($image['tmp_name']);
    if($im_w != 'O' && $im_h != 'O'){
        $im->cropThumbnailImage($im_w,$im_h);
    }

    $fp = fopen($path, 'w'); //the line that is causing the error to occur. line 864.
    $im->writeImageFile($fp);
    return 1;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've had a look through various PHP/Linux fixes for permissions, The /images/ directory and subdirectories currently have permission: `755`

Can anyone help me with a solution. Comment if you need to know anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using 777, it might be that the owner of the web files is different to the one that is trying to write to that directory. I believe 755 only allows the owner of the file to write/edit, whereas 777 allows any user.

Comment: Any drawbacks with 777?

Comment: Not a sysadmin but as far as I'm aware... If you're on shared hosting or allow anonymous FTP then 777 isn't the best idea. If you're on a dedicated server then you should be fine.

Comment: Cool, I'm on a dedicated server. :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Simply entered the command into my linux command line:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/username/public/website.com/public/x_images/
```

Comment: THIS IS A TERRIBLE LIFE CHOICE. You are allowing people to upload files into a place that they can access the files from, and setting the files to be executable. This means you are allowing people to run arbitrary code on your server.

Comment: Do you have a solution?